# Insert action on the table without primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Hello I have table in the database which consist only of foreign keys. This table structure is  like below:

Code is generated by VS in Database first :

```
public partial class DeviceUsage
    {
    public int StorageId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceInstanceId { get; set; }

    public virtual DeviceInstance DeviceInstance { get; set; }
    public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

As You can see all keys are foreign from 3 other tables.

I'm aware that EntityFramework don't like tables without primary keys.

But even that I need to ask you if there is any possibility to make it work or I am forced to add new column Id to my table?

Comment: Primary keys could be also the join of the columns already present (if the three values together are unique of course)

Comment: All three FK are primary keys in their columns ( with identity) so they are unique

Comment: Can't you just make the trio of these values your PK on the table and be done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your primary key.You don't need to add extra `Id` column, you can set one of those properties as primary key with `[Key]` attribute. For example:

```
[Key]
public int StorageId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this article about [Entity Framework and Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) it seems that your answer is

```
public partial class DeviceUsage
{
    [Key] 
    [Column(Order=1)] 
    public int StorageId { get; set; }
    [Key] 
    [Column(Order=2)] 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key] 
    [Column(Order=3)] 
    public int DeviceInstanceId { get; set; }

    public virtual DeviceInstance DeviceInstance { get; set; }
    public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I forgot to mention that I use database first model so I'm not supposed to use data annotations

Answer (score 0):

I think that inserting is not possible without primary key.
Just add

```
[Require]
public int DeviceUsageId {get;set}
```

and let it be, you dont have to use this PK

Comment: It's Database first model so You can't see it in class code but all of  properties are [Required]

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try use fluent api to define primary key:

HasKey(d => new { d.StorageId , d.UserId, d.DeviceInstanceId });